# Query YouTube API for most liked videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am experimenting with YouTube's API, and I am trying to figure out how to return an ordered list of videos by the most number of likes.

I know I can access the number of likes using the video list query, but that is not going to get me what I need.

I need the search query response to have the videos already sorted by most liked.

Is there any query to the API that will do that?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API does not support [ordering](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) video search results by likes.

Comment: Yes I looked at that documentation already. However, because I see a lot of people list the "most liked videos of YouTube" I figure there must be some way of ordering that. What do you believe they do in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Order by rating `order=rating` and number of results with `maxResults=` For example:

```
fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&channelId=${CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=1&order=rating&type=video&key=${API_KEY}`)
```